# Android ImageView with high resolution crash

Tags: android, xml, exception

I have an activity which contain only one `textView` and an `ImageView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >


    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

    <ScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" >
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="330dip"
            android:id="@+id/civil_seminar_image"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/seminar"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

when this ImageView loads and image with normal size , its ok , but when it loads an image with large size and high resolution , it crashes my application and gives me this exception

```
Failed looking up window
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@4356f810 does not exist
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8911)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8902)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:934)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:449)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

I searches a lot through Stack and Google as well , all I got is the advice not to load this large image, I also tried to put it in a `ScrollView` to scroll it but also failed, any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display a very large image on the screen, you've got to downsize it. I guess this is not the answer you want to hear/read, but is the only way to do it.

To avoid bad quality when zooming, you can increase the inSample size on zoom and decode your original image resource again with the increased inSample size.

As a workaround, you can try to load your image on a WebView:

```
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", "<img src='file:///android_res/drawable/example.png' />", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: You mean I couldn't even scroll it if its height was grater than screen size?

Comment: No, the problem is not the width or the height of the image. The problem is the amount of memory that image occupies. If it's very large, the system can't load it on the screen and throws an exception or an OutOfMemory error.

Comment: That was a very good idea , but cannot zoom it in and out , but with this , thanks a lot for your good solution